# Python - Finding the longest word in a text file error

Tags: python, text, txt

I am trying to find the longest word in a text file and it keeps on saying:
`ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`

```py
def find_longest_word(filename):
    with open(filename,'r+') as f:
        words = f.read().split()
        max_len_word = max(words,key=len)   
        print('maximum length word in file :',max_len_word)
        print('length is : ',max_len_word)
  
print(find_longest_word('data1.txt'))
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: It's because `words` is an empty sequence I guess...

Comment: Btw, `max_len = len(max_len_word)`  no need to iterate all again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This should work for you:**

```
from functools import reduce

def find_longest_word(filename):
    f = open(filename, "r")
    s = [y for x in f.readlines() for y in x.split()]
    longest_word = reduce(lambda x, y: y if len(x) < len(y) else x, s, "")
    print("The longest word is", longest_word, "and it is", len(longest_word),"characters long")

    return longest_word
  
print(find_longest_word('input.txt'))
```

Comment: It says that reduce is not defined.

Comment: check the updated answer. you have to import that from `functools`

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the code inside the function and it works but without the function declaration.

I see that your code is missing indentation on line 2. Also, you want to print a return value from the function but your function does not return anything. So maybe your code should be like this.

```
def find_longest_word(filename):
    with open(filename,'r+') as f:
        words = f.read().split()
        max_len_word = max(words,key=len)
        max_len = len(max(words,key=len))       
        return max_len_word, max_len
```

And the usage of the function should be like this.

```
word, length = find_longest_word('data1.txt')
print("max length word in file: ", word)
print("length is: ", length)
```

Comment: answered, but thank you for contributing!